# How to get query to work with Declare @Lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the following code to work, however, it is giving me an error at the last `Select` statement. The error that I am receiving is:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Could someone please assist in resolving this issue? Thank You.

```
declare @Lookup table(
    Id int identity(1, 1)
  , SongTitle nvarchar(512)
)

insert into @Lookup(SongTitle)
select *
from (
    values('Deuce')
         , ('Strutter')
         , ('Black_Diamond')
         , ('Parasite')
         , ('Strange_Ways')
         , ('Rock_Bottom')
         , ('God_of_Thunder')
         , ('Love_Gun')
         , ('She')
         , ('I_Stole_Your_Love')
)

select Albums.AlbumName
     , Songs.SongTitle
      , Songs.Writers
      , Songs.Vocals
      , Songs.SID
      , Songs.TheTime
from Albums A
inner join Songs S 
    on A.AID = S.AID
inner join @Lookup L
    on L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle
order by L.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an alias for your derived tables

```
insert into @Lookup(SongTitle)
select *
from (
    values('Deuce')
         , ('Strutter')
         , ('Black_Diamond')
         , ('Parasite')
         , ('Strange_Ways')
         , ('Rock_Bottom')
         , ('God_of_Thunder')
         , ('Love_Gun')
         , ('She')
         , ('I_Stole_Your_Love')
) AS v; -- <<< provide alias for derived tables
```

If you assign an alias to a table, use the alias instead of the table name.

```
select A.AlbumName -- <<< use alias instead of table name
     , S.SongTitle -- <<< use alias instead of table name
      , S.Writers
      , S.Vocals
      , S.SID
      , S.TheTime
from Albums A
inner join Songs S 
    on A.AID = S.AID
inner join @Lookup L
    on L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle
order by L.Id;
```

Comment: Once I do that.... I get the following errors on all the fields......... The multi-part identifier "Albums.AlbumName" could not be bound.

Comment: @WayneBarron If you assign an alias to a table, use the alias instead of the table name to reference fields in the table.

Comment: That did it.
Thank you so much.
Now to add it to my site... You Rock, have a great rest of the weekend.

Comment: @WayneBarron You too mate ;)-

Comment: @TT. . . .  You should point out that the alias for a subquery or values allows you to name the columns.  This is the only way to assign column names in this case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Absolutely right... I gave precendence to solving the OP's problem. I'll leave that in comments for him.

Comment: @WayneBarron As Gordon rightly points out: the alias for a derived table is required because otherwise there is no way to refer to the columns within that derived table. In the first query you have you are not referring to them yourself, but SQL Server does require the alias though.

Comment: Thank you for that information TT and Gordon. you both rock my friends. Have an awesome rest of the week. Wayne